# Ruby on Rails - Javascript/jQuery to Haml

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I'm trying to implement this in my Ruby on Rails application. The only thing what doesn't work is the Javascript code. I already tried %script and :javascript. But for some reason it doesn't load. When I hover over the radio button it doesn't show anything.

Javascript/jQuery (From jsfiddle):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#container').on('mouseenter', '#radiobtn', showBox);
$('#container').on('mouseleave', '#radiobtn', hideBox);

function showBox(e){
    var x = e.pageX + 20;
    var y = e.pageY + 20;
$('#hoverbox').fadeIn();
$('#hoverbox').offset({ left: x, top: y });
}
});

function hideBox(){
$('#hoverbox').fadeOut();
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/wrN2u/387/

Own Javascript file:

```
:javascript
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#container1').on('mouseenter', '#radiobtn', showBox);
  $('#container1').on('mouseleave', '#radiobtn', hideBox);

  function showBox(e){
    var x = e.pageX + 20;
    var y = e.pageY + 20;
    $('#hoverbox').fadeIn();
    $('#hoverbox').offset({ left: x, top: y });
  }
 });

function hideBox(){
$('#hoverbox').fadeOut();
}
```

HAML:

```
!!!
 %html
  %head
   = javascript_include_tag 'options.js'

    #container1
      %input{:name => "optradio", :type => "radio", :id => "radiobtn"}option1
      #hoverbox
    #container2
      %input{:name => "optradio", :type => "radio", :id => "radiobtn"}option2
      #hoverbox2
```

Comment: The jsfiddle works for me. If there is haml code you are referencing that is broken, be sure to include it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9744169/include-inline-js-in-haml) might be of help to you. Also I noticed in your js-fiddle that the Javascript is not indented. If you are using HAML, then indentation is critical. Make sure your JS begins on the first indentation of the second line after :javascript

```
:javascript
  $(document).ready( function() {
    alert('working');
  } );
```

Alternatively. If you are trying to include a js *file* with HAML you'll need

```
= javascript_include_tag "my_js"
```

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11455551/how-do-import-a-javascript-file-into-a-haml-view).

Also, if this doesn't help. It will be super helpful to see your HAML file.

Comment: My javascript file already gives me a error at :javascript. Error: Statement expected.

Comment: have you written :javascript in your options.js file? If so, remove it. That is HAML code.

Comment: I changed it but it stil does nothing on hover.

Comment: Nevermind I fixed it! I was missing the id at the input-fields and ofcource a little bit with your help.